# Output caching in IIS doesn't work for Wordpress php files

Tags: iis-7.5, wordpress, cache

I enabled output caching for php files

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <serverRuntime frequentHitThreshold="1" frequentHitTimePeriod="00:00:30" />
      <caching>
         <profiles>
           <add extension="*.php" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:00:59" location="Any" varyByQueryString="*" />
         </profiles>
      </caching>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Caching works for PHP test file which prints time

http://www.ahangbaz.com/time.php

but it doesn't work for wordpress (date is printed on page on 3rd line)

http://www.ahangbaz.com/index.php/4002/omega-el-producto/

I am not using any plugin in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
varyByHeaders="x-original-url"
```